# hiredis error message string is messy code

Tags: hiredis

code snippet:

```
        std::function<void(const void *& buf, int& size)> f = [data2, read_buf,key_name](const void *& buf, int& size) {
        auto ctx = data2->GetContext();

        void *reply = NULL;
        auto status = redisGetReply(ctx, &reply);

        if (status == REDIS_OK) {
            redisReply *r = (redisReply *) reply;

            char *data_buf = 0;
            int data_size = 0;

            if (GetData(r, data_buf, data_size, 3, 2)) {
                if (read_buf->capacity() < data_size) {
                    read_buf->resize(data_size * 2);
                }

                memcpy(&(*read_buf)[0], data_buf, data_size);

                buf = (const void *) &(*read_buf)[0];
                size = data_size;
            }
        }
        else {
            std::cerr << "[redis-io]: subscribe get message returns status: " << status << ", Error Code : " << ctx->err << ", Error Details : " << ctx->errstr << ", Channel Info : " << key_name << std::endl;
            throw runtime_error("[redis-io] subscribe get message returns error.");
        }

        if (reply != NULL)
            freeReplyObject(reply);
    };
```

the problem is when redisGetReply(ctx, &reply) returns error and enter the else branch, the printed out error message string of ctx->errstr is messy code, which is unreadable as follows:

[messy code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmMQM.png)

How to fix the issue to show error message normally? Great appreciate.